Stop Mode 2 (deep sleep) doesn't work with STM32l053R8T6 MCU
I am working with my custom PCB with STM32L053R8T6. My code works just fine when I run it in debug without any stop mode (deep sleep). It enters to the RTC and button interrupts perfectly. However, when I want to make the MCU enter to sleep mode the debug in Keil says:

JLink Info: CPU could not be halted
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 15 (R15) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 16 (XPSR) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 0 (R0) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 1 (R1) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 2 (R2) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 3 (R3) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 4 (R4) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 5 (R5) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 6 (R6) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 7 (R7) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 8 (R8) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 9 (R9) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 10 (R10) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 11 (R11) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 12 (R12) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 13 (R13) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 14 (R14) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 15 (R15) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 16 (XPSR) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 17 (MSP) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 18 (PSP) while CPU is running
***JLink Error: Cannot read register 20 (CFBP) while CPU is running

The code below gives the above output on Keil with JTAG debuging:
#include "main.h"
#include "clock_conf.h"
#include "sleep_conf.h"

uint32_t counter = 0;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Configure_PWR(void);
void EnterStop2Mode(void);

int main(void)
{
  /* Configure the system clock to 80 MHz */
  SystemClock_Config();

    /* Configure Power IP */
  Configure_PWR();
  
  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {

    /* Enter Stop mode 2 */
    EnterStop2Mode();

    /* At this point, MCU just wakes up from Stop mode 2 */
  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  /* HSI configuration and activation */
  LL_RCC_HSI_Enable();
  while(LL_RCC_HSI_IsReady() != 1) 
  {
  };
  
  /* Sysclk activation on the HSI */
  LL_RCC_SetSysClkSource(LL_RCC_SYS_CLKSOURCE_HSI);
  while(LL_RCC_GetSysClkSource() != LL_RCC_SYS_CLKSOURCE_STATUS_HSI) 
  {
  };
  
  /* Set AHB & APB1 & APB2 prescaler*/
  LL_RCC_SetAHBPrescaler(LL_RCC_SYSCLK_DIV_1);
  LL_RCC_SetAPB1Prescaler(LL_RCC_APB1_DIV_1);
  LL_RCC_SetAPB2Prescaler(LL_RCC_APB2_DIV_1);

  /* Disable MSI */
  LL_RCC_MSI_Disable();
  while(LL_RCC_MSI_IsReady() != 0) 
  {
  };

  /* Set systick to 1ms in using frequency set to 16MHz */
  LL_Init1msTick(16000000);
  
  /* Update CMSIS variable (which can be updated also through SystemCoreClockUpdate function) */
  LL_SetSystemCoreClock(16000000);
}

void Configure_PWR(void)
{
  /* Enable Power Clock */
  LL_APB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB1_GRP1_PERIPH_PWR);

  /* Ensure that HSI is wake-up system clock */ 
  LL_RCC_SetClkAfterWakeFromStop(LL_RCC_STOP_WAKEUPCLOCK_HSI);
}

void EnterStop2Mode(void)
{
  /* ######## ENABLE WUT #################################################*/
  /* Disable RTC registers write protection */
  LL_RTC_DisableWriteProtection(RTC);
 
  /* Enable wake up counter and wake up interrupt */
  /* Note: Periodic wakeup interrupt should be enabled to exit the device 
     from low-power modes.*/
  LL_RTC_EnableIT_WUT(RTC);
  LL_RTC_WAKEUP_Enable(RTC);
  
  /* Enable RTC registers write protection */
  LL_RTC_EnableWriteProtection(RTC);
  
  /* ######## ENTER IN STANDBY MODE ######################################*/
  /** Request to enter STANDBY mode
    * Following procedure describe in STM32L4xx Reference Manual
    * See PWR part, section Low-power modes, Standby mode
    */
  /* Reset Internal Wake up flag */
  LL_RTC_ClearFlag_WUT(RTC); 
  
  /* Check that PWR Internal Wake-up is enabled */
  if (LL_PWR_IsEnabledFastWakeUp() == 0)
  {
    /* Need to enable the Internal Wake-up line */
    LL_PWR_EnableFastWakeUp();
  }
  
  /* Set Stand-by mode */
  LL_PWR_SetPowerMode(LL_PWR_MODE_STOP);
  
  /* Set SLEEPDEEP bit of Cortex System Control Register */
  LL_LPM_EnableDeepSleep();
  
  /* This option is used to ensure that store operations are completed */
#if defined ( __CC_ARM)
  __force_stores();
#endif

  /* Request Wait For Interrupt */
  __WFI();
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
#endif

The code below works fine in debug:
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    Examples_LL/RTC/RTC_Alarm_Init/Src/main.c
  * @author  MCD Application Team
  * @brief   This example code shows how to use STM32L4xx RTC LL API to configure
  *          an alarm.
  *          Peripheral initialization done using LL initialization function.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2017 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "clock_conf.h"
#include "rtc_conf.h"
#include "led_conf.h"
#include "lpuart.h"
#include "bc660.h"
#include "sleep_conf.h"
#include "gpio_conf.h"

uint32_t counter = 0;

//#if (USE_TIMEOUT == 1)
//uint32_t Timeout = 0; /* Variable used for Timeout management */
//#endif /* USE_TIMEOUT */

/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
  * @brief  Main program
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* Configure the system clock to 80 MHz */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize LED2 */
  LED_Init();

  /*##-1- Configure the RTC peripheral #######################################*/
  Configure_RTC();

  /*##-2- Configure Alarm ####################################################*/
  /* Configure RTC Alarm */
  Configure_RTC_Alarm();

    /* Configure Power IP */
    Configure_PWR();

    /* Configure Alarm and Button Pins */   
    Configure_EXTI();
    
    /* Configure LPUART1 (LPUART IP configuration and related GPIO initialization) */
    Configure_LPUART();
    LL_mDelay(2000);

    
  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  { 
  
  }
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
#endif

/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
  */


You should ask this in a programming stack, such as stackoverflow

@DavideAndrea It's perfectly fine to ask microcontroller-specific programming questions here.

@Lundin. I didn't say it was wrong to ask here. It may be fine but it's unlikely to get as much help as in stackexchange. I wish to help OP by suggesting a better stack than this one.

@DavideAndrea This is the better one, since in case the problem happens to be related to hardware, the question is still on-topic here. On SO when you ask a microcontroller question and it's 50/50 caused by software or hardware, then it's also 50/50 if your question will get closed as off-topic. Besides, most who follow the embedded tag on SO lurk around here as well.

It's probably that you did not enable debugging in low power modes.
In STM32IDE, it's a simple setting (put enable in Configurations->Debugger->Device Settings->Debug in low power modes
For Keil, I think you'll need to set some bits in a register manually. I can't test it now but it should be register "DBG_CR".

Thank you for the reply @bananeeg . I checked the register and yes it was set to 0. However, it still doesn't change after I added DBGMCU->CR |= DBGMCU_CR_DBG_STOP; . Is there anything else I should do before changing this register?

@NicatAli I checked the reference manual but didn't see any special conditions to write to this register. I'd try changing the register directly in the debugger rather than by code, in case it's a silly coding error.  But otherwise, I have no idea.

Yes, I haven't found anything relevant in the manual either. I've also tried modifying the register value directly in the debugger, but unfortunately, it didn't take effect. I'll keep researching this issue and update you here if I find anything helpful.
